# How to avoid incorrect distance between conveyor items in AnyLogic?

Tags: anylogic

The error of incorrect distance between conveyor items occurs sometimes during the simulation. I thought the conveyor item can detect by itself if there is enough space to let the agents in.

I tried changing the length of the conveyor, where the error occured, or changing the position of entering the convey system, but it didn't help solving the problem. What should I do?

The error message:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: root.conveyZurFTM.conveyorEnter.?<MHLSettings>.conveyorSystems_xjal[5].pathControllers[0]:

Internal error: Incorrect distance '-1.0003827046600744E-4' between conveyor items {ConveyorItem {agentId=1142394, conveyor=conveyor2, LE=0.6000000000000001, TE=0.55, length=0.05, motion=bi{t0=834406.0570343151, v0=0.0, a=0.0}, phantom=false, direction=FORWARD}, ConveyorItem {agentId=1142393, conveyor=conveyor2, LE=0.7498999617295341, TE=0.6998999617295341, length=0.05, motion=bi{t0=834406.0571343144, v0=1.0, a=0.0}, phantom=false, direction=FORWARD}}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an internal material handling library error.

As far as I know, you can try these first:

1. Run latest 8.8.5 version if possible. It should be fixed, but that is not true in all cases.
2. Try different seed despite not being the best workaround. If the error is not frequent, you can skip "wrong" seeds.
3. Of course the best solution is to update library, therefore to send your issue to AnyLogic support.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).